# conditionally define a block in twig 2

Tags: twig, symfony, templating

so heres the use case:

- render a login form block in dynamic page structure, but only if user is not authenticated
- block must not be defined if not authenticated (to preserve dynamic page structure)

**twig 2.2**
**symfony 3.2**

---

In a base template, I'm only rendering a block if its defined (not 'not emtpy')

### base.html.twig

```
{% if block('left_sidebar') is defined %}
      <div class="col-md-2">
           {{- block('left_sidebar') -}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
{% else %}
      <div class="col-md-12">
{% endif %}
```

---

### index.html.twig

For the above to work the block cant be defined at all (which is entirely designed).  The following renders the block anyway, and I cant' figure out why.

```
{% if not is_granted('IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED') %}
    {% block left_sidebar %}
        {% include ':blocks:block__login.html.twig' %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

I'm wondering if this is'nt working because of the same reason that the base template code **does** work.  That is that the blocks are compiled before runtime, and the conditional statements are executed at runtime.

Can anyone please confirm that this I'm right? Or correct me if I'm wrong?

**edit**

I've tried forcing the result of the condition to both true and false, and the block is rendered in either case.

Comment: `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`

Comment: looks like theyve aliased one to the other. No difference, but good shout.  I tried forcing the result of the test to both true and false, and the block is still rendered.

Comment: what about something like that : ` {% if app.user and is_granted("IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED") %}` ?

Comment: nope, it still renders even if you force true or false.

Comment: Why not just render the block empty, eg. evaluate the condition inside the block?

Comment: because the rest of the layout of the page is dependent on the conditionally rendered sidebar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, to wrap this up, as it seems to be a problem occurring in a few places, my suspicions are correct in that its a compile/runtime issue.

Blocks are compiled and because the if statement is at runtime one cant control the other.

[heres the github issue thread](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/2393) if anyone wants more info.

Answer (score 1):

The `block()` function appears to return a falsey value if nothing or only white space was output in it, so you can wrap the block in a truthiness test and in the child template make sure it is empty if you don't want it to show.  Something like this worked for me:

base.html.twig:

```
{% if block('left_sidebar') %}
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {% block left_sidebar %}{% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
{% else %}
        <div class="col-md-12">
{% endif %}
```

---

index.html.twig

```
{% block left_sidebar %}
    {% if not is_granted('IS_FULLY_AUTHENTICATED') %}
        {% include ':blocks:block__login.html.twig' %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig compiles your templates into php classes, which you can see in the symfony `cache` directory, and blocks are methods in those classes. This means that blocks are always defined at compile time and conditionals like yours only determine if they are "executed".

For your use case, I would reccommend to to put the call to `is_granted` in the base template. Then you would not need to include any `if` element in `index.html.twig` because defining the sidebar block will have no effect if it is never used.

There is no real performance hit to defining unused blocks since the parsing of twig blocks only happens at compile time. Defining blocks whether or not are used is done, for instance, in symfony's own form component.

Comment: yeah this is what I thought was happening, but I dont want to put the condition the base template as it'll be needed elsewhere.   My issue is that I need 2 conditions, one to determine whether the side bar is rendered, which might have other stuff in it other than a login form, and 2, should the login form be rendered or not, either there or elsewhere.

Comment: But why do you need to define the block depending on these conditions? You could as well move the `if` statement inside the block and only render the `include()` call when the user is logged in.

Comment: because the sidebar needs to be conditionally displayed in other situations that arent related to login

Comment: Take care when putting is_granted in base template, custom 4xx and 5xx errors may use the same base layout where security hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: yeah, thats one of the reasons I dont want the if statement in the base template Alain, but it doesnt look like I have a choice.